# How to merge JSON files in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, vscode-tasks

Currently I'm using a custom `task.json` file to compile and run C and C++ code in Linux:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [

        {
            "label": "PIYUSH Compiler",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [

                "-g",
                "${relativeFile}",
                "-o",
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out",
                "&&",
                "clear",
                "&&",
                "./${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Now there is a build file from Sublime text:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "python3 /home/piyush/Documents/CPHelper/Main.py\"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
        }
    ]
}
```

I want a JSON file  to merge both my custom `task.json` file and this Sublime Text build file in a single `task.json` file.

How to do it?

Comment: Is a task JSON file the equivalent of a Sublime build system?

Comment: no, there is a different format of writing task.json (which is build system for vs code) and sublime text build system .